# Use Observable In Angular To Get Information From Express API

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and struggling to figure out how I get information from my express API. I am simply trying to get a story from my story model in Express from Angular. Please note that if I request said story in Express it works. However I cannot figure out how to use Observable in Angular. Here is my code:

**Express**

models/stories.js

```
//Require Mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const StorySchema = new Schema({
        title: String,
        body:String,
        author: String,
        date: Date,
        rating:Number,
        published:Boolean,
        tag:String},
    {collection: 'Stories'}
);
let Story = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema );

module.exports = Story;
```

story.js (route):

```
  let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let Story = require('../models/stories');
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Story.findOne({_id:id}, (err, story) => {
        res.send({story:story});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Angular**

story.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


export interface Story {
  id: String;
  name: String;
  body: String;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoryService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)  { }

  getStory(id: string): Observable<Story> {
    return this.http.get<Story>('http://127.0.0.1:3000/story/' + id);
  }
}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Story, StoryService} from '../models/story.service';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now My problem is, what do I have to add to home.component to get a story to be viewed in the actual page? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#subscribe-in-heroescomponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the angular tutorial, it's really good. You may want to look here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

As an answer to your question, you can Inject the `StoryService` in your `HomeComponent`, so that you can use its methods.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private _storyService: StoryService) {
       // inject in the constructor
       // the instance could be used in the component class with `this._storyService`
   }

   ngOnInit() {

   }

   // let's say that this method is fired whenever you want a new story
   // maybe on a button click from your HTML
   // requires an id parameter
   getMyStory(id: string) {
       this._storyService.getStory(id).subscribe((data) => {
           console.log(data);  // this is the data returned from your API
       })
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far. So how do I do it if I just want to run the function. Like clicking a link to the story from the home page?

Comment: Or maybe if its easier, how do I display all users?

Comment: @JoeAlvini: If you directly want to use the service(HTTP Request/Observable) in your template, you may want to look at the `async` pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe. And what users?? Make a request to get users through your service(make a different method), use the returned data(you will be able to do it by assigning the return data to a class variable),  or directly use in the template through the `async` pipe.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for all the help!! This was a bit easier than I thought, but I wouldn't have been able to do it without your help. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeAlvini: Haha, you would have!